# Rails nested resource params in reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I've spent a while trying to debug this behavior unsuccessfully, so I'm hoping for help figuring out why my nested resource parameters appear to be getting included in the URL in the wrong order. For some reason, adding and deleting lessons for a course works, but editing a lesson crashes because ActiveRecord tries to find a lesson using the course ID and vice versa.

Course and lesson models

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

Lessons controller

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  
  def index
    @lessons = Lesson.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
    @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
    authorize @lesson
  end

  def edit
    authorize @lesson
  end

  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
    @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
    @lesson.course_id = @course.id

    if @lesson.save
      redirect_to course_lesson_path(@course, @lesson), notice: "Lesson was successfully created."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    authorize @lesson
    if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
      redirect_to course_lesson_path(@course, @lesson), notice: "Lesson was successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @lesson
    @lesson.destroy
    redirect_to course_path(@course), notice: "Lesson was successfully destroyed."
  end

  private
    def set_lesson
      @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
      @lesson = Lesson.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:title, :content, :course_id)
    end
end
```

Routes

```
  resources :courses do
    resources :lessons
  end
```

And what shows up when I do rails routes:

`edit_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/edit(.:format)`

However, when I actually edit a lesson, the parameters seem to get switched, which causes a crash. See below for an example of where it thinks the fourth lesson is the course.

URL: `/courses/fourth-lesson/lessons/forensic-science-344/edit`

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LessonsController#edit
can't find record with friendly id: "fourth-lesson"
              
  private
    def set_lesson
      @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id]) <- Crashes on this line
      @lesson = Lesson.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Update: here's the form for editing a lesson.

```
.container
  = simple_form_for([@course, @lesson]) do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?
  
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :title
      = f.input :content
      %small
      = f.error :content, class: 'text-danger'
  
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary my-4'
```

Comment: Where is the code where the URL gets created? (Like in a form, maybe?) Did I miss it? Sorry if I overlooked...

Comment: Where does it happen that the path gets switched?  Is it the link to the edit form, the update call that the form makes, or when the save is successful and it redirects to the show path?

Comment: I added the code for the form. As for where the path gets switched, the crash happens before the edit gets saved. Unsure how to tell when it happens apart from that - any advice on pinning that down further?

Comment: @Greg We need the code where the edit link is created. This could probably happen by the sequence of passing objects: for example `edit_course_lesson_path(lesson, course)` would give an error similar to what you are getting. The correct way would be: `edit_course_lesson_path(course, lesson)`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I didn't pass in the course parameter on the edit link. I had `link_to 'Edit', edit_course_lesson_path(lesson)`.

It should have been `edit_course_lesson_path(@course, lesson)`.

Thanks for everyone's patience, and many thanks to [Deepesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207394/deepesh-kakani) for finally getting it into my head to look at the edit link.

Comment: You might want to delete the question since it was resolved in a way that is pretty unlikely to be helpful to others since it was a simple omission. The question will most likely be closed anyways which removes it from seach indexes.

Comment: `You might want to delete the question since it was resolved in a way that is pretty unlikely to be helpful to others since it was a simple omission`

Rails documentation is a chaotic mess, this question helped me a lot. No need for deletion. I'm writing this only to bump and postpone deletion ;)